# How to stop for loop in React till asynchronous action is done?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component and inside of it I am communicating with API (here I put timeout instead for simulation). I make some calls inside for loop to update arrays on current interation indexes. Finnally I want to console.log all arrays with added data. And here is the problem. Loop is going through all iterations and doesn't wait to finish asynchonous tasks so it's printing empty arrays with annotation that there are data but just came now.

I tried to add useState but I didn't solve the problem.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

function Ingredients() {
    const heatingStepsTime = [];
    const heatingStepsTimer = [];

    function getTimes(i, type) {
        if (type === "time") {
            setTimeout(() => {
                heatingStepsTime[i] = i;
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            setTimeout(() => {
                heatingStepsTimer[i] = i + 1;
            }, 1000)
        }
    }

    const getProcess = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            getTimes(i, "time");
            getTimes(i, "timer");
        }
    };

    useEffect(getProcess, []);
    console.log(heatingStepsTime);
    console.log(heatingStepsTimer);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            test
        </div>
    );
}

export default Ingredients;
```

Is there a way to stop for loop iteration in React so it will continue when asychronous tasks are done?

Comment: @giorgimoniava But how to use it inside for loop?

Comment: are you using a promise? or async/await?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
function App() {
    function getTimes(i) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(i);
        }, 1000);
      });
    }

    const [heatingStepsTime, setHeatingStepsTime] = useState([]);

    const getProcess = () => {
      const promises = '0'.repeat(10).split('').map((c, i)=>getTimes(i));
      Promise.all(promises)
      .then(result=> setHeatingStepsTime(result));
    };

    useEffect(getProcess, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
          {heatingStepsTime.map((p,i)=><div key={i}>{p}</div>)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-szrhwk

> Explanation:

```
function getTimes(i) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(i);
        }, 1000);
      });
    }
```

To simulate the API, you should simulate it with a promise. This timer will resolve the promise when it times out.

```
const [heatingStepsTime, setHeatingStepsTime] = useState([]);
```

You want to store your result into a state so that react knows to render the result

```
'0'.repeat(10).split('')
```

This is just to simulate your for loop... you may ignore this if you have multiple API calls... just replace it with

```
const promises = [apiCall1(), apiCall2()];
```

```
Promise.all(promises)
      .then(result=> setHeatingStepsTime(result));
```

this will wait for all the promises to resolve and store the result into the state

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. In React we need to use useState to update arrays properly through all iterations. Here is fixed code - maybe someone will have similar problem so here is solution:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function Ingredients() {
  const [heatingStepsTime, setTime] = useState([]);
  const [heatingStepsTimer, setTimer] = useState([]);

  function getTimes(i, type) {
    if (type === "time") {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setTime(currentTime => currentTime.concat(i))
      },1000);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setTimer(currentTime => currentTime.concat(i))
      }, 1000)
    }
  };

  const getProcess = () => {
                for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                  getTimes(i, "time");
                  getTimes(i, "timer");
                }
            }

useEffect(getProcess, []);
console.log(heatingStepsTime);
console.log(heatingStepsTimer);
if (heatingStepsTime[2] && heatingStepsTimer[2] && heatingStepsTime[2] === heatingStepsTimer[2]) {
  console.log("Works!", heatingStepsTime[1], heatingStepsTimer[1])
}

  return (
    <div className="App">
      test
    </div>
  );
}

export default Ingredients;
```